# SplitterPanel not forwarding resize events to children

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a SplitContainer in it.  In the "panel2" SplitterPanel that it creates by default, I have a PictureBox with Dock=Fill.  At runtime, when I resize the window (by dragging the edge of the form, or dragging the splitter bar), the PictureBox changes size, but I never receive a SizeChanged event.  The panel2 SplitterPanel does receive SizeChanged events, though.

Is there some reason why the SplitterPanel isn't raising the SizeChanged events on child controls?  Is there another event it fires instead maybe?  I can't find any documentation one way or another.

Comment: Is this `Splitter` or `SplitterContainer`? I think `SplitterPanel` - if there is any - may not be the default `WinForm` Control, so it might have different behavior...

Comment: I put together a test app just as you described:  a form with a SplitContainer, and in panel2, a PictureBox.  Using designer, I attached a handler to the PictureBox's SizeChanged event.  Works fine.  I suspect you've either not attached the handler properly, or an exception is being raised preventing it from reaching your code.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - That's weird, because that's literally exactly what I'm doing and it's not working.  The Layout event still fires, though, and I'm doing the same thing for both events, so I should be registering event handlers correctly (and I'm just creating them through the designer anyway).  What version are you using?  I'm on VS2013 framework 4.5.

Comment: @Ian - It's SplitterContainer.  It creates two SplitterPanel by default for you to put things in.

Comment: VS2015, .NET 4.5.2 (default for new project)

Comment: @DonBoitnott - It works if I switch to .NET 4.0, but broken in 4.5 and 4.5.1.  So it seems like a framework bug.  Can you confirm for me?

Comment: Works for me in 3.5, 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, and 4.6.1.